Flutter In-app purchase: Can't retrieve and purchase a subscription
I've set up and created a subscription but I can't retrieve any of the subscriptions when querying for product details. But when I use the product's id the query is successful. Can anyone help and explain to me?
I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase
final String _kLifetimeSubscriptionId = 'l0420239999'; // subscription's id
final String _kLifetimeSubscriptionId = 'l04202399'; // product's id

final ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse = await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails({_kLifetimeSubscriptionId,}.toSet());

My setup subscriptions
My setup in-app products
My expected: Can purchase subscription
